# save Json object to a class with variable name same as in Json

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to save Json object to a class with variable names same as in Json (Just like what Gson does). My problem to use Gson is, The datatype of the class variable in json changes according to datas available in server. For example, some times, it contains a list of data,and some other time, it contains "" for null. my Gson crashes while dealing with both the cases for a single code.

Comment: Check your solution here http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Can you provide **examples** of **all** the different JSON responses you have to parse? Because your question is very ambiguous... how many different possibilities do you have for the data (there is **one** JSON field that may change or there are **many**)? what values it can have (is only `List<String>` and empty `String`, or there are other posibilites)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal JSON object, GSON is for predefined datatype and it makes handling data easier. If you have changes in your datatype, better use JSON itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use GSON2 if you have used an old version of the GSon.